# Finding the derivative of $h(x)= \frac{f(x)^2}{\sqrt{g(x)}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to evaluate $h'(2)$ when $h(x)= \frac{f(x)^2}{\sqrt{g(x)}}$ given:

$f(2)=5$

$f'(2)=2$

$g(2)=\frac{1}{10}$

$g'(2)=\frac{-1}{20}$

When I try to differentiate using the quotient rule, I get stuck as the square root of -1/20 doesn't exist in the reals

$h(x)=\frac{f(x)^2}{\sqrt{g(x)}}$

$h'(x)=\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(f(x)^2)\sqrt{g(x)}-f(x)^2\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\sqrt{g(x)}\right)}{\sqrt{g(x)}}$

$=\frac{2f'(x)\sqrt{g(x)}-\frac{f(x)^2}{2\sqrt{g'(x)}}}{g(x)}$

Any help and guidance would be appreciated

Comment: yes what you did was great, now just substitute in values for $f$, $f'$, $g$, $g'$ and you are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made some mistakes while applying the quotient rule, 
$$h(x) = \frac{f(x)^2}{\sqrt {g(x)}}$$
$$\therefore h'(x) = \frac{2f(x)f'(x)\sqrt{g(x)}-f(x)^2\frac{g'(x)}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}}{g(x)}$$
Hope this helps.

Comment: wouldn't it just be applied under d/dx = (vu'-uv')/v^2

Comment: Yes, you're right but the thing is you also need to account for the fact the the expression involves the square root of $g$ and the square of $f$. This can be done using chain rule

Comment: Or if it makes more sense, in the quotient rule, let $u=f(x)^2 \therefore u' = 2f(x)f'(x)$, let $v=\sqrt {g(x)} \therefore v' = \frac{g'(x)}{2\sqrt{g(x)}}$ and just plug these in the quotient rule formula

Comment: oh totally forgot about that. Thanks heaps ! :)

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of problems, logarithmic differentiation makes life easier
$$h(x) = \frac{f(x)^2}{\sqrt {g(x)}} \implies \log(h(x))=2\log(f(x))-\frac 12 \log(g(x))$$
$$\frac {h'(x)}{h(x)}=2\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac 12\frac {g'(x)}{g(x)}$$
$${h'(x)}={h(x)}\times\frac {h'(x)}{h(x)}=\frac{f(x)^2}{\sqrt {g(x)}}\left(2\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}-\frac 12\frac {g'(x)}{g(x)} \right)$$  Just simplify.